# How to copy data from Database to another Database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this structure:

```
Database1
New(table)
--categories(column)
----id - name - parent_id - created_at - updated_at

Database2
Old(table)
--categories(column)
----id - category - parent - created_at - updated_at
```

How can I copy the data of the categories from `Database1` to `Database2` via SQL?

Comment: Use _export_ and _import_ functionality? `SELECT` from one `INTO` the other?  There are several solutions, perhaps more detail would be good

Comment: @Martin But the names of the column is different !

Comment: @Martin and I can not change the old one because it's the data of another app just want to copy to my app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
INSERT INTO Database1.new_table 
SELECT id,category as name,parent as parent_id,created_at,updated_at 
       FROM Database2.old_table
```

This query for copy database with current datetime

```
INSERT INTO Database1.new_table 
SELECT id,category as name,parent as parent_id,
       now() as created_at,now() as updated_at 
FROM Database2.old_table
```

Comment: worked perfectly  +how can I put value to created_at,updated_at  like the now date?

Comment: INSERT INTO Database1.new_table 
SELECT id,category as name,parent as parent_id,now() aas created_at,now() aas updated_at 
       FROM Database2.old_table

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Database1.New SELECT * FROM Database2.old
```

User should have read access on  Database2.old and write on  Database1.new

Comment: you notice  the names of the column is different  ?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
INSERT INTO DATABASE2.Old(ID, CATEGORY, PARENT, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT) 
SELECT ID, NAME, PARENT_ID, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT
FROM DATABASE1.New
```

This will do it

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it